# PreAuthorize error handling

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using `Spring Oauth2` and `Spring Pre-post Annotations` With `Spring-boot`

I Have a service class `MyService`. one of `MyService` methods is:

```
@PreAuthorize("#id.equals(authentication.principal.id)")
public SomeResponse getExampleResponse(String id){...}
```

can i control in some manner the json that is returned by the caller Controller?

the json that is returned by default is:

```
{error : "access_denied" , error_message: ".."}
```

I Want to be able to control the `error_message` param. I'm looking for something similar to:

```
@PreAuthorize(value ="#id.equals(authentication.principal.id)", onError ="throw new SomeException("bad params")")
public SomeResponse getExampleResponse(String id){...}
```

One way i thought of doing it is by Using `ExceptionHandler`

```
@ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
public Response handleAccessDeniedException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request){
    ...
}
```

but i can't control the `message` of the exception. and also i can't be sure that this `Exception` will be thrown in future releases

Comment: The `{error : "access_denied" , error_message: ".."}` looks like the output from the Spring Boot default error handler. Is that what you are using?

Comment: yes @DaveSyer i'm using Spring boot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring Boot docs on error handling: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling. One way you can control the JSON is by adding a `@Bean` of type `ErrorAttributes`.

```
@Bean
ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
    return new MyErrorAttributes();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The documentation part is not really clear and it will be great to have an `How To` on this subject.  `DefaultErrorAttributes` method: `addErrorDetail` how can i control the `Throwable error` message that is passed to `ErrorAttributes`?

Comment: If the exception comes from `@PreAuthorize` you can't control it much (or at least I can't see why you'd want to). What you can do, I suppose, is add a custom `AccessDecisionManager`, but that's really not very mainstream.

Comment: Hi @DaveSyer, I have the situation `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and principal.user.isEnabled() == true and principal.user.isConfirmed() == true")` and i want to differ which of constrains throws a AccessDeniedException. Then handle it and throw my own exception depending on unsatisfied condition. Or only what i can to do its to write my own aspect and throw exceptions by my own?

Comment: @royB Have you found an answer to your original question? I have exactly the same problem as you i.e. I want to throw different exceptions according to different conditions...

Comment: @DaveSyer. Does the only way of throwing different exceptions according to different conditions mean implementing an `AccessDecisionManager`? Say I want to throw a custom `PaymentRequiredException` instead of a plain `AccessDeniedException` if the condition in the preauthorize is not matched. Is there a way of doing this with the current implementation of  Spring boot and spring security?

Comment: I have opened a bounty as I think this question is very interesting and I have upvoted the question as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the best solution so far is to use the ControllerAdvice support, add an @ExceptionHandler for the IllegalArgumentException, or whatever PreAuthorize is throwing, and then inspect the message body itself to see if it's a spel related error and customize the errors returned to the client-

http://www.baeldung.com/2013/01/31/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring-3-2/

Answer (score 9):

Implement AccessDeniedHandler

```
@Override
public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SomeJsonModel jsonResponse =new SomeJsonModel();
        mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), jsonResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException();
    }
}
```

SomeJsonModel will be your own POJO/model class which you can control
And add that access denied handler in Resource Server Configuration

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers(SECURED_PATTERN).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,SECURED_PATTERN).access(SECURED_WRITE_SCOPE)
                .anyRequest().access(SECURED_READ_SCOPE).and()
              .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(newAuthExceptionEntryPoint())
                .accessDeniedHandler(new MyAccessDeniedHandler());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It was not working for me when I implemented AccessDeniedHandler. So I created a ExceptionHandler function inside AuthenticationEntryPoint and marked the class as
@ControllerAdvice.

Please find the code below

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Component  
public class EmrExceptionHandler implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmrExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(convertObjectToJson(new ErrorResponse(ResponseMessages.NOT_AUTHORIZED)));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {AccessDeniedException.class})
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                         AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException {
        logger.error("AccessDenied error: {}", accessDeniedException.getMessage());
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value());
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(convertObjectToJson(new ErrorResponse(ResponseMessages.NOT_PERMITTED)));
    }


    public String convertObjectToJson(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use `ExceptionHandler` to handle all Exceptions. However, when I debug application I realise that wrong Exception class was imported. Make sure you import correct Exception class.

```java
// First time I import
import java.nio.file.AccessDeniedHandler;

// Correct import
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
```