# Custom AccessDeniedHandler not called

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have implemented a custom AccessDeniedHandler:

```
public class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {


    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException,
        ServletException {

        System.err.println("Access DENIED ");
        response.sendRedirect("/public/error.xhtml");

    }
}
```

And configured it in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/docs/**", "/public/**", "/javax.faces.resource/**", "/index.html", "/uploads/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/public/login.xhtml")
            .failureUrl("/public/login.xhtml?l=error")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/public/login.xhtml?l=success")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .deleteCookies()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/public/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&l=logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(new MyAccessDeniedHandler())
        .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
}
```

I am using `@PostAuthorize` with a custom `PermissionEvaluator`

The `PermissionEvaluator` is working, but the `AccessDeniedHandler` is never called. Instead I am only getting the stacktrace of the Access Denied exception.

thanks for the Help.

EDIT: Added Stacktrace

```
javax.el.ELException: /secured/organisation/ou.xhtml @17,67 value="#{ouBean.activeOU.name}": org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.getValue(UICommand.java:218)
at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeMenuItemContent(BaseMenuRenderer.java:249)
at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeMenuItem(BaseMenuRenderer.java:215)
at org.primefaces.component.breadcrumb.BreadCrumbRenderer.encodeMarkup(BreadCrumbRenderer.java:75)
at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:113)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.renderView(RewriteViewHandler.java:186)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:368)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
... 96 more
Caused by: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPostInvocationAdvice.after(ExpressionBasedPostInvocationAdvice.java:62)
at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PostInvocationAdviceProvider.decide(PostInvocationAdviceProvider.java:41)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AfterInvocationProviderManager.decide(AfterInvocationProviderManager.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:73)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
at de.uni_freiburg.brainlinks_braintools.rais.service.OrganisationalUnitService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c32d2659.getById(<generated>)
at de.uni_freiburg.brainlinks_braintools.rais.model.OrganisationalUnit.getById(OrganisationalUnit.java:218)
at de.uni_freiburg.brainlinks_braintools.rais.managedBeans.OrganisationalUnitBean.getActiveOU(OrganisationalUnitBean.java:168)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor320.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
... 103 more
```

Comment: Hope in your case this happens when the user is already logged in but does not have access to certain resources due to authorization levels. right?

Comment: yes. user is logged in but tries to access a resource he has no access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok It seems to be working when I change

```
servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE",
            "Development");
```

To

```
servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE",
            "Production");
```

Anyone may elaborate on why this is the behaviour? I would expect the 403 error page to be displayed and the stack trace in the log.

Comment: check your code there should be some logical checks like the code given below
'FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

Application application = facesContext.getApplication();

if (application.getProjectStage() == ProjectStage.Development) {
    // Define development settings
}

or 

FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
if (facesContext.isProjectStage(ProjectStage.Development)) {
    // Define development settings
}'

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was that in addition to my CustomAccessDeniedHandler there was also a global resource exception handler with @ControllerAdvice. I solved this by rethrowing the exception in the global handler (as advised here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6908), then my CustomAccessDeniedHandler gets executed.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResourceExceptionHandler {
...
    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity accessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException e) throws AccessDeniedException {
        log.info(e.toString());
        throw e;
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1.You might want to set error page like this in your AccessDeniedHandler

```
 public void setErrorPage(String errorPage) {
      ....
    }
```

Because the exception is valid but it is unable to find the page hence setting here might help

## 2. If everything fails you can also you can try this approach where in you can use the url pattern

```
.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDeniedPage.htm")
```

Error page will always start with "/"

```
@Controller
public class MyAccessDeniedHandler {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/accessDeniedPage.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectAccessDenied(Model model) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println(" Redirect Access Denied Handler!");
        return "myerrorpage";
    }
}
```

## 3. In addition to above you can still use the custom AccessDeniedHandler by simply map it via a bean config

```
.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDeniedPage.htm")
 @Bean( name = "/accessDeniedPage.htm" )
    public AccessDeniedHandler  authenticationEntryPoint() {    
        return new MyAccessDeniedHandler();
    }
```

or

```
.accessDeniedHandler( this.acessDeniedHandler() );
 @Bean( name = "/accessDeniedPage.htm" )
        public AccessDeniedHandler  accessDeniedHandler() {    
            return new MyAccessDeniedHandler();
        }

public class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {    

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException,
        ServletException {

        System.err.println("Access DENIED ");
        response.sendRedirect("/public/error.xhtml");

    }
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81845/discussion-between-bwright-and-mudassar).

Comment: Also what are you using for MVC ? in case of spring mvc there are chances where in the search for the bean happens inside the dispatcher, so need to drill down if the the /accessDeniedPage.htm is being searched in your mvc mapper instead of the securty mapper

Answer (score 0):

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
.and()
.exceptionHandling()
.accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandler())
```

i think you need to pick your own `MyAccessDeniedHandler()` here

Comment: Sorry typo in my code above. It actually says `.accessDeniedHandler(new MyAccessDeniedHandler())`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. My custom AccessDeniedHandler was not being triggered. So I marked the AuthenticationEntryPoint class as @ControllerAdvice and added a new function with the annotation @ExceptionHandler . This is working for me now. You can see the complete code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62929627/6414086)